# Allow to search by synonym tags with wildcard

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, tag-synonyms, wildcards

Intro. I made a search for [`-[tag:status-*] user:me is:q`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A339911%20-%5Bstatus-*%5D+is%3Aq) to see what number of post I have where SO employee did not reacts yet. Then I copied this search request and tried to use it for "Stack Overflow on Russian Meta"... [without desired effect](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A176217+-%5Bstatus-*%5D+is%3Aq). I.e. results still contain a posts with red tags and wildcard tag is not recognized.

> [image: wildcard tag is not used]

This is happening because all red tags which are main for English-spoken sites are synonimized for localized sites. E.g. [status-completed](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) is synonym for [статус-завершено](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE). So I need to change `status-*` to `статус-*` if I want to do the same thing on ruSO.meta.

My request is as following: allow to search by wildcard tag even in case when it is synomym. This is needed to make uniform search on any site of the SE network.